# What is the Google sheets formula to calculate the working hours of timestamp difference for a specific working hours?

Tags: google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-formula, date-difference

With the condition:

1. The working hours from Monday to Sunday from 09:00 - 18:00
2. Full holiday (no working) only on public holiday such as January 1, May 1, December 25

A. Ticket received on Sunday, April 30, 2023 at 17:30
B. Ticket responded on Tuesday, May 2, 2023 at 09:30

What is the Google sheets formula to calculate the working hours of timestamp difference between ticket received and ticket responded above (in minutes)?

The expected answer is 60 minutes: I have 30 minutes left on Sunday but still not responded, skip on Monday because it is holiday, and used 30 minutes on Tuesday to reply it.

Tried to use NETWORKDAYS.INTL but it does not work. Really appreciate with your help.

[Docs link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IAkDHA6CYVfYGp55dgNp812sZ2g1dZmvb_5ztpoEQ0/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Hi! I just want to clarify something about including Weekends as NETWORKDAYS automatically excludes weekends.

Comment: It would help if you could share a sample sheet with demo data (of few more scenarios than just one single example) and expected output(manually entered) so that it gives a clear picture for us to work it out

Comment: Hi @Babanana correct it is including weekends. I do not know any other possible formula besides NETWORKDAYS, because I need to consider working hours from 09:00 to 18:000.

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow please help to take a look at this file https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19IAkDHA6CYVfYGp55dgNp812sZ2g1dZmvb_5ztpoEQ0/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow thanks for the formula, somehow it is working for normal cases. I just updated the sheet with more scenarios, please apologize that I do not share another scenario earlier. Could you please help to check? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Updated formula***:

```
=map(F4:F,G4:G,lambda(created,response,if(len(created)*len(response)*(response>=created),let(Σ,sequence(days(response,created)+1,1,created,1),
           Λ,ifna(filter(Σ,iserror(xmatch(Σ,tocol(Holidays!A2:A,1))))),
           sum(map(Λ,lambda(Δ,round(ifs(
                     min(Λ)=max(Λ),  max(min(Λ+C1,response),Λ+B1)-min(max(Λ+B1,created),Λ+C1),
                     min(Λ)=Δ,       ifs((Δ=int(created))*(timevalue(created)<=C1),C1-max(B1,timevalue(created)),Δ<>int(created),"09:00:00",1,),
                     max(Λ)=Δ,       ifs((Δ=int(response))*(timevalue(response)>=B1),min(C1,timevalue(response))-B1,Δ<>int(response),"09:00:00",1,),
                     1,              "09:00:00")
                     *24*60))))),)))
```

[image]

Comment: Updated the formula. Please do test it out **extensively** n' see if you come across any other non-working scenarios...

Comment: Hi @rockinfreakshow Thank you so much for your help. I found 1 last scenario in the sheet that should return to 0 because it replied during holidays. Would you mind helping me to update the formula? Thank you so much

Comment: PERFECT. I will close this thread now. Thank you so much for your help @rockinfreakshow! Really appreciate your help and time.